# Any Android media player which occupies the least space in Split View mode?

Tags: media-player, epub, tablet

I am using the Split View functionality of my Android tablet to read e-books while also listening to their audio-book versions. For this purpose, I need to have most of my screen given to the e-pub reader and only a narrow bar assigned to the media player. I have already tried the VLC media player and some other ones but they take up about one-fourth of the valuable space.Do you know any media players with the desired functionality in Split View mode?